# Load script after Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, reload

(Sorry for my bad English)

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id='ad_fulldiv'>
//Some text and images
<div id='ad_content''>
require_once('/include/adcontent.inc.php');
</div>
</div>
```

I have also a Jquery code with Ajax request. In the file adcontent.inc.php there is a switch loop which echoes random content what depends on the content in a database. After the user clicks on a button a Ajax request is called which updates the database. If the file returns 'true' (update is successfull) the div ad_content should fadeout en should be reloaded with adcontent.inc.php. It should have other content now, because the Database is updates.

But how can I reload the div? I think the load option doesnt work. I tried to do that, but exactly the same content is loaded.

Comment: you'll have to post more code. Or even better, a jsFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a5GbN/ I hope this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your includes/adcontent.inc.php script return the div content rather than true/false?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/adcontent.inc.php',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (data) {
            $('#ad_content').html("Loading...");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data!='error'){
            $('#ad_content').html(data);
        }else{
            $('#ad_content').html("<span style='color:red;'>Error!</span>");
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
            $('#ad_content').html("<span class='error'>Error!</span>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Fixed! Thanks! It was a fault in my other script that prevents the script from direct call, but many thanks for the replies!